# Round Corners in java fx pane

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying  to get  round bottom corners in my application, but the result is this:

[image]

This is the CSS file:

```css
.mainFxmlClass {
  #pane{
    -fx-background-size: 1200 900;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 18 18;
    -fx-border-radius: 0 0 18 18;
    -fx-background-color: #FC3D44;
  }
}
```

And my main class:

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Preview.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

How can I remove these white corners?

Comment: `-fx-border-radius: 10 10 0 0;`
 `-fx-background-radius: 10 10 0 0;`

Comment: Try making the fill of the scene as transparent,
scene.setFill(Color.Transparent);

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally after so much research and some help from the spanish version of Stack O. the most easy way to remove the white corners is this:

In the main class you must add:

```
scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

and:

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

The only problem is that `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT` will leave you without the close button so you must make it by yourself.
The final result is this:

[image]

Comment: This works but you also have to make sure you are setting your pane to transparent by using `setBackground()`. This method requires a couple extra hoops to jump through, but it's easy once you know how to do it. 
`yourPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));`

Answer (score 9):

> If You Don't want to background Color the just try this: `-fx-background-color: transparent;`

OR

```
-fx-background-size: 1200 900;
-fx-background-radius: 30;
-fx-border-radius: 30;
-fx-border-width:5;
-fx-border-color: #FC3D44;
```

OR

```
 -fx-background-size: 1200 900;
 -fx-border-radius: 10 10 0 0;
 -fx-background-radius: 10 10 0 0;
 -fx-border-color: #FC3D44;

  /* top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left corners, in that order. */
```

Answer (score 4):

But if you want to have a picture for background instead of a solid color while you put the background in Css:

```
-fx-background-image: url("backs/background.jpg");
```

you should put such code in your Main class:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1024,768);
rect.setArcHeight(60.0);
rect.setArcWidth(60.0);
root.setClip(rect);
```

[I found it here](https://apilevel.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/java-fx-stage-with-rounded-corners-with-background-image/)

Comment: Try to round the image corners before use it as background.